# how to read a byte array from sqlite database and convert to bmp and store in an int array

Tags: java, android, arrays, sqlite, android-viewpager

1. i am looking to read from a sqlite database. database holds byte array info from an image(blob type).

   2. convert the byte array into a bmp.
   3. store that bmp in an int array.

   Story: i have entered an image into a database from an image view when the image changes in that image view i can save it to the sqlite database. i convert it into a byte Array and in it goes at the push of a button.Code for conversion below. Bmp refers to a Bitmap

   Bitmap myBit = ((BitmapDrawable) myImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                   ByteArrayOutputStream myBos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                   myBit.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, myBos);
                   byte[] img = myBos.toByteArray();

   Now i want to view all the images that i have stored in that database.
   I have used a PagerAdapter to view items that are already in my drawable folder as follows

   ```
   private int[] image_resources = {R.drawable.community_btn_txtpn,R.drawable.logo_design,R.drawable.photo_camerabtn_txt,
   R.drawable.plant_for_gallery,R.drawable.save_for_sharing_txt,R.drawable.seed_savebtn_txt,R.drawable.seed_sharebtn_txt,
   R.drawable.seeds_for_sharing_txt};
   ```

   i need that array to hold the images form my database.

and code from the database query to read from the database. i have gotten this far

```
    public Cursor getImage(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor C = db.rawQuery("select image from " + TABLE_IMAGE,null);

        return C;
    }
```

> code from the PagerAdapter

```
 package com.jonnyg.gardenapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by reiko_000 on 24/04/2016.
 */
public class CustomSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {





    private int[] image_resources = {R.drawable.community_btn_txtpn,R.drawable.logo_design,R.drawable.photo_camerabtn_txt,
    R.drawable.plant_for_gallery,R.drawable.save_for_sharing_txt,R.drawable.seed_savebtn_txt,R.drawable.seed_sharebtn_txt,
    R.drawable.seeds_for_sharing_txt};



    private Context ctx;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public CustomSwipeAdapter(Context ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return image_resources.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view ==(RelativeLayout)object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout,container,false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view_gallery);
        TextView textView = (TextView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_count);
        TextView photoSlide = (TextView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.txtVPhotoSlide);
        imageView.setImageResource(image_resources[position]);
        textView.setText("Image : " + position);
        container.addView(item_view);





        return item_view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
       //work faster
        container.removeView((RelativeLayout)object);
    }
}
```

Comment: `i convert it into a byte Array and in it goes at the push of a button.`. If you do not tell how you convert an image to a byte array then we will never know whats in that byte array. So how could we ever help?

Comment: `convert the byte array into a bmp.`. What is an bmp?

Comment: `store that bmp in an int array`. Why do you want to do so?

Comment: apologies i though a Bmp was short for a Bitmap. and i have added the code for the conversion

Comment: You did not store bitmaps in the database but png images. Further you do not show how you put them in the database. Once you have pulled them out the database you cannot put them in an int array as images are no integers.

Comment: You have to change your adapter code a bit so it can handle the images from the database.